# PDF Product Labels Generator with Java

Tags: java, templates, label, barcode, bartender

Given dataset of retail products, I need to generate [product labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zssk1.png) containing product description, price, barcode etc by formatting based on given template.
For now I'm using iText but each time the label format is changed I have to change also the java code.
Is there any tool like [Seagull Bartender](https://www.seagullscientific.com/) to design the label template and then generate labels from java app?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, [Seagull Bartender](https://www.bartendersoftware.com/) offer label template design software and provides tools like SDK to include in your java app for label generation.

> To have further confirmation of whether my answer satisfy your question. Please download and try the free trial bartender software and include the ActiveX Automation provided by bartender to your Java App so you can have a try whether it works for your or not.
>
> I do not did Bartender in Java before but the concept of getting label template designed and automate print in application is the same:
>
> 1. Design Label templates using Bartender
> 2. Include `ActiveX Automation` to your Java Apps
> 3. Have your `DataSet of retail products` prepared in Java Apps
> 4. Populate the information to the Bartender File you designed in Step 1
> 5. Execute print process to the Bartender File.